# How to know what line of code causing OutOfMemory from UI's Stage DAG?

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to analyze an issue in my spark job which is failing with an `OutOfMemory` error.

I am trying to analyze the issue by looking at the Spark ApplicationMaster's UI. The UI shows the Stage and Task breakdown of the job, and I'm focusing my analysis on a stage that is experiencing task failures.

The Stage UI has a DAG showing the actual commands/methods being performed in that stage.

The problem is that I have 150 lines of code doing DataFrame transformations and only one line, at the very end, doing an action - saving to parquet.
This means that all the "blue boxes" have the line number of the last line.

Yes, they have some information about the method (window, order, etc.), but I have these methods throughout my entire code, so I have no way of knowing to which line it's referring.

What can I do to find which part of the code is in trouble?

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't know which transformation is causing the problem, I would suggest injecting actions between the transformations, to see which action will recreate the problem.

this is a small utility function I use to make this easy:
(I call it `break`, since it breaks the DAG)

```
implicit class ExtendedDataFrame(val df : DataFrame) extends AnyVal {   
    def break(name: String = ""):DataFrame = {
      if (name.nonEmpty) {
        println(s"About to break DAG for $name")
      }

      val cached = df.cache()
      cached.count
      cached
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
df
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .action
```

will look like this:

```
df
    .map(...).break("map 1")
    .map(...).break("map 2")
    .map(...).break("map 3")
    .map(...).break("map 4")
    .action
```

now when you code fails, you will see in the spark UI the exact line, and in the logs you will see what transformation was about to happen before the failure.

Comment: Thanks. I already have that exact solution, for calling `show()` when I debug. I'm looking for a solution doesn't require intermediate actions.

Comment: Also, This involves `cache()`, which I'm afraid will overload my executors' memory.

Comment: I agree, but on the other hand, not using `cache()`, will force each `break` to evaluate to previous transformations, and that might take a lot of time

Comment: What I did, in the end, was to store every DF to parquet and read it right back. Takes longer, but helps pinpoint the weak link.

Answer (score 2):

I'd review the physical plan of the query and perhaps the RDD lineage, too.

Use `explain` to learn the physical plan (or `df.queryExecution.sparkPlan`) and that's what is going to be executed.

The RDD lineage is available using `RDD.toDebugString` (that you can access using `df.rdd`) that will show you the stages and partitions (= tasks).

With that, I'd register a [SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) and would start listening to `SparkListenerStageSubmitted` and `SparkListenerStageCompleted` events. Listening to `SparkListenerTaskStart` and `SparkListenerTaskEnd` could be helpful, too.

All that will give you fairly good overview what and when has finished or not. No code review, change, recompilation or similar. Nice and clean.

Registering a custom `SparkListener` is possible using `spark.extraListeners` Spark property:

> The comma-separated list of fully-qualified class names of Spark listeners that should be registered (when `SparkContext` is initialized).

See [Spark Listeners — Intercepting Events from Spark Scheduler](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-SparkListener.html).